# URL Request Forwording

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a website such as foo.com
I want to redirect all request for http://foo.com to http://www.foo.com
one way to do this is URL redirect but its not efficient. there is some other way to do this.

Comment: why do you say `its not efficient`? If it's a `301 redirect` then is as efficient as it gets. Search engines will not care how you're redirecting as long as you do it properly.

Answer (score 0):

You should install the IIS Rewrite module from [here](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite) and add this rule in your `web.config` file:

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="Redirect domain.com to www" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="*" />
            <conditions>
                <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="domain.com" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.domain.com/{R:0}" />
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```